# How to prevent openvz container from adding another ip address?

Tags: virtualization, openvz, containers

How to prevent openvz container from adding another ip address ?
I'm using VETH Container.

I used this command to configure the network :

```
vzctl set xxx --save --netif_add ethx,,,FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean addresses assigned to venet0?  You can remove all of them by the following command:

```
vzctl set xxx --save --ipdel all
```

Comment: No i don't mean that
i have veth not venet
so i assign ip from the container not from the host
i'm just building a bridge for every container